# Getting map locations from custom google maps

Tags: api, google-maps

It's a general question for any programming language that can use google maps api...

Is there a way i can get specific locations provided by web sites that use google maps with their own location marks or location info.

For example yellow pages will offer locations that you won't get if you search for it simply from the official google maps web site.

What if also this website doesn't provide API to parse data from?

For further example , a web site may have a map having all locations of restaurants in Canada for instance so i want to get the same information in this map to import it in my map inside my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sites you are referring to have the address and geocode information in their own database. They send you the data in response to your request and render it on the map in your browser using the client-side script API that google map provides.

If that's the case and the site didn't provide a public data service, then no, you can't get those data using the normal way.